# android add item dynamically to listview

Tags: android, listview

i have a listview with checkboxes - and a button that popup an alert dialog with all the checkedboxes that i checked -> now... i need to pass the VALUES FROM THE DIALOG TO LISTVIEW FROM A NEW ACTIVITY (create or add dynamically listview)
One more thing - every time that client click on the possitiveButton - it shuold create a new ListView

```
btnDialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDialog);
        btnDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Diet Product");
                responseText.append("הפריטים שנבחרו הם: \n");

                for(int i=0;i<modelList.size();i++){
                    Models models = modelList.get(i);
                    if(models.isSelected()){
                        responseText.append("\n" + models.getName()+ " : "+models.getProtein() +"\n");
                    }
                }

                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage(responseText.append("\n"+"לחישוב ערכים לחץ המשך " +"\n"+"או חזור לעידכון פרטים"+ "\n"))
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("CREATE NEW MEAL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, close current activity
                                //MainActivity.this.finish();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ItemActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra(models.getName(),"name");
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("BACK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), responseText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
        });
```

[image: a picture is worth a thousand words]

Comment: On a completely unrelated topic: What language is that?

Comment: how have you created the first one? I do not understand why you cannot create the second one in ItemActivity class

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want to pass data from the dialog to the current activity? What do you mean pass from the dialog to a NEW activity?

Comment: hi- for "anned20" i tag it as a android - so i  thought its clear that its android/java - sorry about it.

Comment: sure i can create the second activity "ItemActivity" - but in the ItemActivity i want to have a listview that get the values from the dialog that shown to the client from the first activity

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ItemActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(models.getName(),"name");
```

First, you should use activity context for creating new Intent.

Second, using "intent.putExtra("name", models.getName());" is what you need. You can get models.getName() from second activity as; getIntent.getExtra("name").

Comment: thanks for the comment - its not that simple - i try it allready! i think the issue in my situation is the pass ArrayList<Models> to the new Activity!